# Task Manager full screen popup window

Tags: vbscript, scheduled-tasks, hta

I am very new to all of this. I am attempting to get windows "Task Scheduler" to run a app that pops to the front of the users screen.

I initially tried using a VBS msgbox using the 4096 code to keep it on top. That works but the window that pops up is far to small and I need to change colors for different tasks.

After more research I found how to make a HTA window that I could customize and make full screen. But when task scheduler runs it, it pops up behind the user active window. The users usually have a full screen page up, so they are unable to see the alert.

I don't need the alert to always be on top, I just need it to initially load in front of everything and then the user has to look at it before closing.

It is very possible I'm am making this harder than it should be so I'm open to any option that is better. I'll include the HTA I've been using

```
<html>
<head>
<hta:application 
APPLICATIONNAME = "TEST"
ID = "TEST"
SCROLL = "No"
MinimizeButton = "no"
WINDOWSTATE="maximize"
SINGLEINSTANCE = "Yes"
/> 

<STYLE>
html, body {
background color: #000

 font-size: 100%;
 line-height: 10em;
 margin: 10;
 padding: 0;
}
h1 {font-family: Arial;
 color: #ff0000;
 font-size: 5em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;
}
h2 {font-family: Arial;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 7em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;
}

</STYLE> 
</script>
</head>
<body scroll="no">
<br>
<h1>ATTENTION!</h1>
<h2>Check your inventory.<br></h2> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a title in your HTA after the `<head>` opening tag: `<title>Check Your Inventory</title>`. This will give your window a meaningful name.

then replace this `</script>` with this:

```
<script language="vbscript">
Sub Window_OnLoad()
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    ms = "1000"
    objShell.Run "ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w " & ms,0,True 
    objShell.AppActivate "Check Your Inventory"
End Sub 
</script>
```

This will run when the window opens up. Essentially, after 1000 milliseconds it will attempt to activate a window with the title you just gave it.

I don't always have a lot of luck with AppActivate, but there is a lot of information online and on SO about it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I put the code in. It still isn't popping to the front. It's behind whatever window the user has open. If you can think of anything else please let me know. I'll do some more searching into appactivate and self.focus. See what I can figure out.